# how to loop through a string and create an array? - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, arrays, listbox

I have a string where I have created a template so to speak.

{

```
Dim myvariable as string
Richtextbox1.text = Richtextbox1.text & "The dog jumped over the" & myvariable & "to find the fox."
```

}

I have a list box that contains a list of options that loads into the variable example: fence, bucket, etc.

So the sentences would read like

1. The dog jumped over the fence to find the fox
2. The dog jumped over the bucket to find the fox

Right now I have it coded to display into a rich text box but everything is in the same rich text box.

I'm trying to load the string into an array at the end of each loop this way I can then have each sentence separated.

What would be the best way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the name of your ListBox control is `myLstBox` and your RichTextBox control is `myRchBox`

```
Private Sub WriteOnRichTextBox()
    For Each xStr As String In myLstBox.Items
         myRchBox.AppendText("The dog jumped over the " & _
                              xStr & " to find the fox.")
         myRchBox.AppendText(ControlChars.NewLine)
    Next
End Sub
```

You need to loop on all the items found on the listbox.

Comment: Hey thanks John but that part I already have coded correctly. Right now my codes loops through the list box and inserts the word into the variable and then writes the sentence to the richtext. What I was trying to figure out is after it has already looped through the sentence and put the word into place how can I put the sentence into an array before grabbing the next sentence? See right now when I hit my "go" button my richtextbox populates 3 sentences into a rich text box. Each sentence contains a word from the list box.

Comment: I am trying to figure out to separate the sentences at the end of each loop. Example. The dog jumped over the fence...done put this into a string....sentnce 2..done...put that into a string..etc.So sentence 1, sentence 2, and sentence 3 are in some sort of array where I can do something else with the code.